# Multi-select fields on Generic Inquiry

Tags: acumatica

How do you filter on multi-select fields on generic inquiry?
Assuming your data looks like this :

```
ROW         VALUES
A           1,5
B           3,4,5
C           5
D           1,2,3
E           2,4
```

And you want too search for records where there is either 1 or 3. So it should show rows A, B & D. I'm not sure if its possible. So the alternative would be write a custom screen and manipulate via view delegate. I could be wrong though.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The `PXMultiSelector` editor control persists the values in `string` format

How to filter depends on the format. Email address for example have a pre-determined format. For those you can add a standard string filter like `Field Contains c@d.com`

[image]
[image]

That wouldn't work for numbers. If you search for number `1` in list `2,4,15` it would return the result because `15` contains `1`. To workaround this issue you can add a custom unbound DAC field. In the DAC field property getter you can parse the value of the multi-selector field and reformat it to a pre-determined format like `,2,4,15,` and filter on `,1,` instead of `1`.

Comment: If your question is strictly about the 'or' filter, you can add those in the Condition Operator column. There is parenthesis support for more complex filtering.

Comment: thank you @Hugues Beauséjour. the thing is i'm using my multiselect field as parameter condition. so if my parameter is ",c@d,g@h,". it's not going to hit that row as the query seems to be looking for a row where both c@d & g@h is in the data field. hope i'm making some sense.

Comment: I don't see how this is a problem. Instead of putting a constant in Value 1 column put your parameter identifier inside square brackets.

Comment: You can also use formula editor in Value 1 column to add separator to search value if necessary.

Comment: ">  the query seems to be looking" have you tested that with a profiler? I tested example I provided so it likely does not seem to be behaving that way.